# How do Linux global brokers

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, security

I have a Linux VPS.
I need to go outside and I try to proxy

export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8123"
export https_proxy="https://127.0.0.1:8123"

But not all agents.
I have an nginx that needs access to external data.
How can I set up all agents.
Go tor or proxy

thank you

Comment: Tor isn't an HTTP proxy, can you clarify where Tor comes into this at all?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly do you need :

- So if your NGinx *itself* needs to access the outer world via proxy - it is done via Tor's TransPort port and DNS resolver, it's a way better, because it's protecting you from DNS leaks. The forwarding itself is done via firewall on by-user basis(iptables)
- If you run something inside NGinx, like PHP or other active content - it's usually done by elaborating stuff like cURL, but if it will lead to a massive code rewrite - firewall forwarding is used as well.

In both cases you **don't** forward the mandatory connections, like incoming requests, connection between nginx-to-php, php-to-local-mysql etc, but all the rest goes through Tor via firewall rules.